# How do I call mathematical object which is a group supporting multiplication by a number from R?

Tags: group-theory, average, percentile

Suppose we have a group $G(T,+)$. It naturally supports "multiplication by an integer", e.g. $5 \cdot t = t + t + t + t + t$ for any $t \in T$.

However, this can't be expanded to $Q$ or $R$: there is no easy way to define what $2.5 \cdot t$ means. But I can define some operation $m: R \times T \to T$ to support that, getting $(G(T, +), m)$.

Is there a name for such pair?

For example, $m$ can be "stretching" for time duration, or plain multiplication with rounding for integers. Possible applications: calculating averages and percentiles.

**UPD**: desired properties of $m$:

$m(0, t) = \theta $

$m(1, t) = t $

$m(2, t) = t + t$

$m(b, m(a, t)) = m(ab, t)$

Comment: You have to say what properties you want for tis "some operation", otherwise the question is meaningless. A group action is such an action of $R$ on $T$ satisfying certain axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group action of $\mathbb R$ on a set $X$ (ie a map $\varphi:\mathbb R\times X\to X$ such that $\varphi(t,\varphi(s,x)) = \varphi(s+t,x)$ and $\varphi(0,x) = x$) is called a [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Formal_definition).

The situation OP is describing seems to be a set equipped with a group structure and a flow which are compatible in that for any integer $k\in \mathbb Z$, $\varphi(k,x) = x^k$. I don't know that such structures have been explicitly studied and I don't think they have a specific name.